# Loop in R not appending all the values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a testing data-set of 88 observations. I have built a model and predicting on this new data-set.

Here is the twist. I am adding a new column to it and trying to store the predictions into a dataframe.

My training and test data are all matching.
Now when I execute this loop, I am not getting the desired output.

```
#creating an EMI vector
em = c(10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000)
#my dataframe where i want to store predictions
v <- c()
v <- data.frame(v)

for(i in em){

  newdata$EMI.Amount=i

  prediction=predict(rf,newdata,type="response")

  kl <- table(prediction)
  v <- rbind(v,kl)

}
```

I am getting predictions of only the last EMI value from the vector `em`.
i.e for 1,00,000.

Here is the output

[image]

I want the output for each `em` vector i.e the predictions of the binary class to be in the dataframe like this.
[image]

Comment: What is the use of 'table' here ? What shape has your 'prediction' ?

Comment: Try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Please `dput(newdata)` and share the results.

Comment: in any case you should probably convert `kl` to a `data.frame` shape that you want, before `rbind`ing it to `v`. And initialize `v`properly (accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run a loop.
Instead I would simply run the code

```
newdata$EMI.Amount <- em
v = predict(rf, newdata, type="response")
```

I hope that is the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure how your code works as it is not reproducible. Maybe you would like something like this?

```
#creating an EMI vector
em=c(10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000)
#my dataframe where i want to store predictions
v<-c()
v <- data.frame(v)
newdata$EMI.Amount<-em
prediction=predict(rf,newdata,type="response")
kl <- table(prediction)
v <- rbind(v,kl)
```